# Is there a short video presenting the basics of UI design?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

I'm looking for a short video (15-45 minutes) presenting the basics of UI design, targeted at developers. Can you recommend one?

Comment: This is probably better-suited for [User Experience SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/). I'm pretty sure it's off-topic for SO.

Comment: It's a sad world where UI design is considered off topic for programming. No wonder so many applications are so badly designed.

Comment: Anyways, I wasn't even aware there was a User Experience SE. Can my question be transferred there, since it's apparently not welcome here?

Answer (score 2):

Lynda.com is a great place for everything front-end using a very developer friendly approach. However to understand UI/UX 15 -45 minutes might be a little too less. Here's a course I found of great value, which is just under 2 hours.

http://www.lynda.com/Web-User-Experience-tutorials/User-Experience-Fundamentals-Web-Design/103677-2.html

This is a part of series on UI/UX you can check out the rest as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these two they helped me alot

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsqOF9JGg4c
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YSA7bnAc1PQ&list=PLUEBcxu4MJ9x0eK6ChtfdkODiRC1naUvc